# JAVA Code for calling REST http method patch in OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have requirement to invoke patch method to external OAuth2.0 server.

I was implement the java code to invoke http rest method patch.
But this code is not much helpful to invoke the patch call.

Requesting you, please help to create a code to invoke 'patch' method.

`

```
importcom.wm.data.*;
    importcom.wm.util.Values;
    importcom.wm.app.b2b.server.Service;
    importcom.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException;
    importcom.sun.security.ntlm.Client;
    importjava.io.*;
    importjava.net.*;
    importokhttp3.Headers;
    importokhttp3.MediaType;
    importokhttp3.OkHttpClient;
    importokhttp3.Request;
    importokhttp3.RequestBody;
    importokhttp3.Response;
    importjavax.sound.midi.Patch;
    importorg.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    importorg.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    importorg.apache.http.client.methods.*;
    importorg.apache.http.Header;
    importorg.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    importorg.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    importorg.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    importorg.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    importorg.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch;
    importorg.apache.http.impl.*;
    importorg.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    publicfinalclasstestPatchCall_SVC
    {
    /**
    *TheprimarymethodfortheJavaservice
    *
    *@parampipeline
    *TheIDatapipeline
    *@throwsServiceException
    */
    publicstaticfinalvoidtestPatchCall(IDatapipeline)throwsServiceException{
    //pipeline
    IDataCursorpipelineCursor=pipeline.getCursor();
    logger("Entered");
    StringURL=IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor,"URL");
    StringrequestData=IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor,"requestData");
    StringHttpMethod=IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor,"HttpMethod");
    //headers
    IData[]HeadersCall=IDataUtil.getIDataArray(pipelineCursor,"HeadersCall");
    if(HeadersCall!=null)
    {
    for(inti=0;i<HeadersCall.length;i++)
    {
    IDataCursorheadersCursor=HeadersCall[i].getCursor();
    Stringname=IDataUtil.getString(headersCursor,"name");
    Stringvalue=IDataUtil.getString(headersCursor,"value");
    headersCursor.destroy();
    }
    }
    pipelineCursor.destroy();
    MediaTypemediaType=MediaType.parse("application/json");
    OkHttpClientclient=newOkHttpClient();
    logger("Initiatingrequest");
    RequestBodybody=RequestBody.create(mediaType,requestData);
    Requestrequest=newRequest.Builder()
    .url(URL).patch(body).addHeader("content-type","application/json")
    .addHeader("Accept","application/json")
    .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer1213ABANCBYD").build();
    try{
    logger("Calling"+request);
    Responseresponse=client.newCall(request).execute();
    logger(response.body().string());
    }catch(Exceptione){
    logger(e.toString());
    }
    //pipelin
    IDataCursorpipelineCursor_1=pipeline.getCursor();
    ObjectresponseData=newObject();
    IDataUtil.put(pipelineCursor_1,"response",responseData);
    pipelineCursor_1.destroy();
    }
    //---<<IS-BEGIN-SHARED-SOURCE-AREA>>---
    privatestaticHttpURLConnectionsetRequestProperty(IData[]headers){
    //TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
    returnnull;
    }
    privatestaticHttpURLConnectionsetRequestMethod(Stringmethod){
    //TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub
    returnnull;
    }
    //---<<IS-END-SHARED-SOURCE-AREA>>--
    /**
    *Theserviceimplementationsgivenbelowareread-onlyandshowonlythe
    *methoddefinitionsandnotthecompleteimplementation.
    */
    publicstaticfinalvoidaddInts(IDatapipeline)throwsServiceException{
    }
    publicstaticfinalvoidpatchMethod(IDatapipeline)throwsServiceException{
    }
    publicstaticfinalvoidRestPatch(IDatapipeline)throwsServiceException{
    }
    }`
```

I am trying to send the patch call data from my server to OAuth 2.0server.

here I using the application as client to OAuth (resource server).

I have implemented the code to get the Bearer token by calling POST http method. and get the token successfully.

After I am trying to call the patch call.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How are you creating any `POST`/`GET` requests needed?

Comment: Please use the edit option in the question than paste it here in the comments.  Also please do the Tour so that you can ask the questions in a manner that's accepted and respected by the community here at stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/tour